# Sort listview by name in ascending

Tags: android, sorting, listview

i have listview and i want to sort it by name in ascending. How can i do it programmatically?

Here's my code

```
public class InformationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;
  private ActorAdapter adapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);

    final ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

Here's ActorAdapter

```
public class ActorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {
  private ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
  private LayoutInflater vi;
  private int Resource;
  private ViewHolder holder;

  public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    actorList = objects;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nama);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());
    Picasso.with(this.getContext()).load(actorList.get(position).getImage()).placeholder(R.layout.progress).resize(110,110).error(R.mipmap.error).into(holder.imageview);
    return v;
  }

  static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageview;
    public TextView tvName;
  }
}
```

I'm beginner in android and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some like this:

```
 final ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

     Collections.sort(actorsList, new Comparator<Actors>() {

            /* This comparator will sort objects alphabetically. */

            @Override
            public int compare(Actors a1, Actors a2) {

                // String implements Comparable
                return (a1.name.toString()).compareTo(a2.name.toString());
            }
        });

    adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row,    actorsList);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You must sort your list before `setAdapter` method.

Comment: I added your code before `listview.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: what happaned at all?

Comment: The listview works fine and shows me the data but the sort function is not works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107334/discussion-between-kristiyan-varbanov-and-michael-julyus-christopher-m).

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
Collections.sort(actorsList, new Comparator<Actors>() {
@Override
public int compare(Actors lhs, Actors rhs) {
    return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
}});
```

Comment: I added your code before `listview.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: this is not right place to put this code please put before
`adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);` this line.